# Php, typed property and lazy loading? How can I check if it's initialized?

Tags: php, types

you know Php 7.2 has typed properties:

```
class Test { }

class Test2
{
    private Test $test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = new Test();
    }
}
```

so far so good, but what if I want to have a lazy created object?

```
public function createIfNotExists()
{
    if ($this->test === null) // *ERROR
    {
    }
}
```

this fails:

> Typed property must not be accessed before initialization

but I want to check either it's been created, not using it. How to?

Comment: Does `isset($this->test)` work?

Comment: [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`!empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) ? & Use the null operator on your property: `private ?Test $test = null;`

Comment: If you always initialize it in the constructor, the test will never fail.

Comment: I think `if (property_exists($this, "test"))` is more appropriate, but Barmar is correct that you should just set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can probably do

```
isset($this->test)
```

Comment: great, this works. I also tried to use $this->test === null, also failed.

Comment: yes because to use `===` you have to access the property @JohnSmith

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 7.4, you can use the [Null Coalescing Assignment Operator `??=`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator) as well in your method

```
public function createIfNotExists()
{
    $this->test ??= new Test();
}
```

It's equivalent to

```
$this->test = $this->test ?? new Test();
```

Which is equivalent to

```
$this->test = isset($this->test) ? $this->test : new Test();
```